# Mochiweb's Scalability Features

Tags: http, erlang, scalability, mochiweb, httpserver

From all the articles I've read so far about Mochiweb, I've heard this over and over again that Mochiweb provides very good scalability. My question is, how exactly does Mochiweb get its scalability property? Is it from Erlang's inherent scalability properties or does Mochiweb have any additional code that explicitly enables it to scale well? Put another way, if I were to write a simple HTTP server in Erlang myself, with a simple 'loop' (recursive function) to handle requests, would it have the same level of scalability as a simple web server built using the Mochiweb framework?

**UPDATE:** I'm not planning to implement a full blown web-server supporting every feature possible. My requirements are very specific - to handle POST data from a HTML form with fixed controls.

Comment: Here's an interesting link to a 1 million user application with Mochiweb: http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-1

Comment: This may already be answered in [Technically why is processes in Erlang more efficient than OS threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708033/)

Comment: @Adam Lindberg I've already read through those series of articles.  They were very enlightening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MochiWeb isn't scalable itself, as far as I understand it. It's a fast, tiny server library that can handle thousands of requests per second. The way in which it does that has nothing to do with "scalability" (aside from adjusting the number of `mochiweb_acceptor`s that are listening at any given time).

What you get with MochiWeb is a solid web server library, and Erlang's scalability features. If you want to run a single MochiWeb server, when a request comes in, you can still offload the work of processing that request to any machine you want, thanks to Erlang's distributed node infrastructure and cheap message passing. If you want to run multiple MochiWeb servers, you can put them behind a load balancer and use mnesia's distributed features to sync session data between machines.

The point is, MochiWeb is small and fast *(enough)*. Erlang is the scalability power tool.

---

If you roll your own server solution, you could probably meet or beat MochiWeb's efficiency and "scalability" out of the box. But then you'd have to rethink everything they've already thought of, and you'd have to battle test it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Probably. :-)

If you were to write a web server that handles each request in a separate process (light weight thread in Erlang) you could reach the same kind of "scalability" easily. Of course the feature set would be different, unless you implement everything Mochiweb has.

Erlang also has great built in support for distribution among many machines, this might be possible to use to gain even more scalability.

Comment: Yes, I'll be using separate processes for each request. And my feature requirements are very specific - to handle POST data from a HTML form with fixed controls.