# How does Erlang implement concurrency without the use of OS threads?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, erlang

If Erlang does its own process creation and scheduling, without utilizing OS threads, how does it make use of multiple CPU cores? My limited understanding is that the OS assigns the CPU cores to OS threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang runs on a virtual machine called BEAM.

The Erlang process runs a separate BEAM VM on each core (using OS threads).

See this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779162/what-kind-of-virtual-machine-is-beam-the-erlang-vm).

Comment: Thank you.  My low reputation doesn't allow me to up tick your response.

Comment: Actually that is not quite right, it runs 1 BEAM VM which has an OS thread for each CPU. That way the beam can move processes between CPUs if it needs too