# Beam VM Scheduler vs OS Scheduler

Tags: erlang, beam

Beam VM breaks the program into small, light-weight processes and has its own scheduler. How does this scheduler works alongside the underlying OS scheduler ? If these are processes, then OS will schedule them accordingly, then how does Beam VM manages the scheduling ?

Answer (score 2):

The Beam VM runs typically one OS process per core, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779162/what-kind-of-virtual-machine-is-beam-the-erlang-vm). So the VM processes are internal, and are scheduled differently.